# Conditional variable assignement in makefile target

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to get conditional assignment in a makefile target, only if it was not set by the requiring target:

```
REPO_PROD = prod
REPO_DEV = dev

.PHONY: ko-build-container
ko-build-container: KO_DOCKER_REPO ?= $(REPO_PROD)
ko-build-container:
    @echo $(KO_DOCKER_REPO)

.PHONY: ko-build-container-dev
ko-build-container-dev: KO_DOCKER_REPO = $(REPO_DEV)
ko-build-container-dev: ko-build-container
```

Unfortunately `make ko-build-container-dev` prints `prod`.
What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is to use a third target, like:

```
ko-build-container-base:
        echo $(KO_DOCKER_REPO)

ko-build-container: KO_DOCKER_REPO = $(REPO_PROD)
ko-build-container: ko-build-container-base

ko-build-container-dev: KO_DOCKER_REPO = $(REPO_DEV)
ko-build-container-dev: ko-build-container-base
```

Comment: Thanks, it's an option. It makes chaining harder though. I could imagine the same issue at deeper level. With this, all target must call `ko-build-container-base` directly.

Comment: I don't see why.  But maybe I don't understand what you mean by "all target must call `ko-build-container-base` directly".  Targets don't "call" other targets, they depend on them.  Is that what you meant?  Of course the other simple option is to set the default value at the global level: `KO_DOCKER_REPO = $(REPO_PROD)` then only override it via `ko-build-container-dev: KO_DOCKER_REPO = $(REPO_DEV)`.

Comment: I mean `ko-build-container-dev` could depend on intermediary targets (things like `ko-build-container-amd64` and so on), and intermediary targets could bring default values while allowing values override if necessary. This doesn't sound easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, with GNU make, the outcome of the conditional assignment (assign or not assign) is decided in a phase where only global variables are available, but the selection of the final value comes from a later phase where inherited target-specific variables are also available. So, even more bizarre than what you observed, after skipping a conditional assignment because a global variable was set, the final value is not necessarily that of the global variable, it can be inherited from a parent target! Demo:

```
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: sub all
all: VAR = all
all: sub
# no global VAR set => assign instead of using inherited VAR = all
sub: VAR ?= sub
sub:
    @echo $(VAR)
$ make
sub
```

```
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: all
VAR = global
# global VAR set => do not assign, use global VAR = global
all: VAR ?= all
all:
    @echo $(VAR)
$ make
global
```

```
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: sub all
VAR = global
all: VAR = all
all: sub
# global VAR set => do not assign... but use inherited VAR = all
sub: VAR ?= sub
sub:
    @echo $(VAR)
$ make
all
```

This strange behavior is reported here: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?18305 and there is also a discussion about whether it should/could be fixed.

Separating the outcome from the selection of the value in conditional assignments is clearly a bug, I think. Nobody would imagine such a weird behavior. Anyway, instead of a target-specific conditional assignment you could use the workaround suggested in the discussion:

```
$ cat Makefile
REPO_PROD = prod
REPO_DEV = dev

.PHONY: ko-build-container
ko-build-container:
    @echo $(or $(KO_DOCKER_REPO),$(REPO_PROD))

.PHONY: ko-build-container-dev
ko-build-container-dev: KO_DOCKER_REPO = $(REPO_DEV)
ko-build-container-dev: ko-build-container

$ make ko-build-container-dev
dev
```

Comment: Thank you for investigating it. It looks like conditional assignment at the target level should be avoided (this seems hardly reliable and intuitive :()